# How can I navigate back to LoginScreen from ProfileScreen having bottomnavbar in compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Here is Code for the reference I have 3 navgraphs one for rootNavs and 2nd one for authentication and 3rd one for in app navigation/bottombar navigation
**RootNavGraph**

```
  @Composable
fun RootNavGraph(tokenManager: TokenManager,navController: NavHostController) {
    NavHost(navController = navController,route=Graph.ROOT, startDestination = Graph.AUTH){
        authNavGraph(tokenManager = tokenManager, navController = navController )
        composable(route=Graph.HOME){
            HomeScreen()
        }
    }
}

object Graph{
    const val ROOT="root_graph"
    const val AUTH="auth_graph"
    const val HOME="main_graph"
}
```

**AuthNavGraph**

```
composable(AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.LoginScreen.route){
                LoginScreen(
                    tokenManager,
                    onClick={
                        navController.popBackStack()
                        navController.navigate(Graph.HOME)
                    },
                    onRegister={
                        navController.navigate(AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.RegisterScreen.route)
                    },
                    onForgot={
                        navController.navigate(AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.ForgotPassword.route)
                    }
                )
            }
            navigation(
                route= AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.ForgotPassword.route,
                startDestination =AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.ForgotPassword.ForgotPasswordScreen.route
            ){
                composable(AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.ForgotPassword.ForgotPasswordScreen.route){
                    ForgotPasswordScreen(navController)
                }
                composable(
                    AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.ForgotPassword.ResetPasswordScreen.route,arguments=
                    listOf(navArgument("email"){type= NavType.StringType})
                ){
                    val email=it.arguments?.getString("email")
                    Log.d("EMAIL",email!!)
                    ResetPasswordScreen(navController, email)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeNavGraph**

```
@Composable
fun HomeNavGraph(navController:NavHostController, paddingValues: PaddingValues) {
    val sharedViewModel:SharedViewModel= viewModel()
    NavHost(navController = navController, route = Graph.HOME, startDestination =BottomBarItem.Main.route ){

        composable(route=BottomBarItem.Main.route){
            MainScreen(navController,sharedViewModel)
        }

        composable(route=BottomBarItem.Profile.route){
            ProfileScreen(navController)
        }

        composable(route=BottomBarItem.Cart.route){
            CartScreen(navController = navController)
        }
        composable(route="details"){
            DetailScreen(sharedViewModel,navController)
        }

        composable(route="catProducts/{id}",arguments=
        listOf(navArgument("id"){type= NavType.StringType})){
            val id=it.arguments?.getString("id")!!
            CatProducts(id,navController,sharedViewModel)
        }

        composable(route="checkout"){
            CheckoutScreen()
        }

        composable(route="orders"){
            OrderScreen(navController)
        }
        composable(route="orderDetail/{id}",arguments=listOf(navArgument("id"){type= NavType.StringType})){
            val orderId=it.arguments?.getString("id")!!
            OrderDetailScreen(orderId)
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeScreen**
with bottomNavBar

```
@Composable
fun HomeScreen(navController: NavHostController = rememberNavController()) {
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            BottomBar(navController)
        }
    ) {paddingValues ->
        HomeNavGraph(navController,paddingValues)
    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomBar(navController: NavHostController) {
    val screens= listOf(
        BottomBarItem.Main,
        BottomBarItem.Cart,
        BottomBarItem.Profile
    )

    val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
    val currentDestination = navBackStackEntry?.destination

    val bottomBarDestination = screens.any { it.route == currentDestination?.route }

    if (bottomBarDestination){
        NavigationBar {
            screens.forEach{screen->
                AddItem(screen=screen,currentDestination=currentDestination,navController=navController)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun RowScope.AddItem(screen: BottomBarItem,currentDestination: NavDestination?,navController: NavHostController) {
    NavigationBarItem(
        label = {
            Text(text=screen.title)
        },
        icon = {
            Icon(imageVector=screen.icon,contentDescription = screen.title)
        },
        selected = currentDestination?.hierarchy?.any{
            it.route==screen.route
        }==true,
        onClick = {
            navController.navigate(screen.route){
                popUpTo(navController.graph.findStartDestination().id)
                launchSingleTop=true
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Now I want to got to LoginScreen on button click from ProfileScreen how can I do it

Whenever I try `navController.navigate(AuthScreen.AuthenticationScreen.LoginScreen.route)` in ProfileScreen then I get this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation destination that matches request NavDeepLinkRequest{ uri=android-app://androidx.navigation/login } cannot be found in the navigation graph NavGraph(0xd750ce95) route=main_graph startDestination={Destination(0x78d845ec) route=home}`

Please help me to resolve this issue